# Npm registry error when installing msgpack-x

Tags: npm, msgpack

When I execute
    npm install msgpack-x
I get an error which says 'msgpack-x' is not in the npm registry.

I am very new to this, any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use the registry JSON dump to see if the file is there:

- Search for it in your search engine of choice, for example:

  - `site:registry.npmjs.org msgpack-x`
  - `domain:registry.npmjs.org msgpack-x`
- If it's there, find the name that comes after `{"_id":`
- Use that in your npm install, for example:

  `npm install msgpack-js-browser`

**References**

- [7 Things A Search Engine You've Never Heard Of Has Over Google And Bing](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2015/05/14/7-things-a-search-engine-youve-never-heard-of-has-over-google-and-bing/#546068f94d49)
- [Perform Site Specific Search With Google, Yahoo and Bing](https://www.maketecheasier.com/perform-site-specific-search-google-yahoo-bing/)
- [Search engine search techniques - Emlev](http://emlev.com/blog/search-engine-search-techniques/)